# When does one use HttpBindNever attribute?

Tags: c#, .net, http

What does the HttpBindNever attribute do? I tried using it with a method (in a controller) that I didn't want to expose as an API action, but then an exception says it can only be used for a class or a property.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`HttpBindNever` attribute is used in the model class to tell Formatter that it should ignore members marked with HttpBindNever during serialization.

If you don't want to expose a method of a controller as an action, use `NonAction` attribute.